# What does it mean for a program to have same `BuildID[sha1]` number as another?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Trying to run an object file which was compiled with gcc, I got this error saying `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. I didn't know what to do with it, so I searched on google.

[This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2330667) question pops up at one of the first places of the results, and at the end there is a guy that prints the output of this command in order to try go get to a solution

```
/usr/bin/file -L $(/usr/bin/which ls)
```

Which gets **the same output** as my computer. Even the build id. Everything.

[image: file output]

From what I've read, this means we are using the exact same program, am I right? If so, what are the implications of that? Does that mean that he just downloaded the same `.iso` file as me? Or that someone has rewrited a custom `ls` file and installed in my computer? Last message of the thread was from July 13th, 2016, and I guess ubuntu must have made changes to their iso in that time(I think), hence changing the build ids.

I need someone to tell me what is happening here... My computer and network could be compromised so please don't discard anything.

Comment: well, SHA1 is a Hashing algorithm, so for the exact same input (the binary value of your file for instance), it will always produce the same output. It is completely expected that multiple instances of the same version of Ubuntu would ship the exact same executable/SO available in the repositories and on distribution disks.

Comment: Also, note that the thread you link to, does not in the end explain how those files came to be linked to ~/bin, and a reboot cleared the issue. I see nothing except the mystery to it that indicates malicious code. Please consider the point of the `which` invocation. `which` will display the path to the executable your command indicates, so its useful for figuring out "which" version of the executable you are actually invoking. in your case, its coming from /bin/, which is where it should be, so no one is tricking you into running a fake version.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not include the complete error message. In particular it makes no mention of which file cannot execute.

It seems unlikely that `$(/usr/bin/which ls)` is the correct command line argument for the `file` command in this situation. Output from the `file` command is far more likely to provide relevant information if the command is invoked on the file which cannot execute (the one whose name is not present in the question because the complete error message is absent). If you invoke the `file` command on the relevant file, its output might provide some insight. Other information which might be relevant includes which version of the compiler you're using and (perhaps more importantly) how you're invoking it.

One simple way to get the error message excerpted in your question is to invoke `gcc` with `-c` and attempt to invoke the object file it produces (which might require adding execute permission to it using `chmod`). In this case the output from the `file` command might look something like this:

```
test.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

If you link that object file against system libraries using a command like `gcc -o test test.o` the output from the `file` command might look more like this:

```
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9c069b3da39bd98ef3e72ba070286936c7807ead, not stripped
```

In short, the ambiguous phrasing of your question does not rule out the possibility that you are attempting to invoke a relocatable object file rather than invoking an executable generated by the linker. If this is not what's going on, you should edit the question to be more specific about what you are attempting.

About the matching BuildID, yes, that means the person who asked the question in the forum you linked happens to have the same `ls` binary you have, but that is completely unrelated to a problem with an Exec format error on an unrelated file, like the one you compiled with gcc.